# how to configure Tor browser to be with only one IP?

Tags: configuration, help

I get set up for just one country, but now need to configure Tor browser to only a fixed ip, if anyone knows, please let me know

Comment: What's your need for a single IP? You may find a VPN better suited to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

As it said in [manual](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en) :

> TrackHostExits host,.domain,…
>   For each value in the comma separated list, Tor will track recent connections to hosts that match this value and attempt to reuse the same exit node for each. If the value is prepended with a '.', it is treated as matching an entire domain. If one of the values is just a '.', it means match everything. This option is useful if you frequently connect to sites that will expire all your authentication cookies (i.e. log you out) if your IP address changes. Note that this option does have the disadvantage of making it more clear that a given history is associated with a single user. However, most people who would wish to observe this will observe it through cookies or other protocol-specific means anyhow.